# How to create a stored procedure with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures

i was wondering if it's possible to create a stored procedure with hibernate ?
or the available is that i can call procedures only ?
please advise.

Comment: Since stored procedures are specific to the database vendor, it doesn't make much sense to create them with a n ORM that is supposted to give you cross-DB support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DAO's or Repositories, or Managers for your entities, you could create custom methods in them like `getPostsFromUserBetweenDates(int id, date start, date finish)` using [Hibernate's Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html). It allows you to write queries in language very similar to SQL but it has the advantage of being fully object-oriented.